# Visual Studio for Mac の「折りたたみ」ショートカットがきかない

Tags: visual-studio

[image: ショートカットがききません]

MacにVisual Studioを入れたのですが、メニューの

[表示] > [折りたたみ] > 以下のメニューがすべてグレーになっていて有効化することができません

ソースコードにマウスカーソルを近づけると ＋ マークが表示されてクリックすると折りたためるのですが、
なぜかメニューがグレーになっているのでキーボードのショートカットがききません

Visual Studioを再インストールしてみましたが現象が解消されませんでした
どのようにしたらこのメニューを有効にできてキーボードショートカットを使えるようになるのか
ご教示いただきたく、よろしくお願いします

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　質問文が途中で終わってしまっているようです。質問文下の「編集」から書き直せますので、ご確認くださいませ。

Comment: ありがとうございます！いま気付きました。。

Answer (score 0):

該当のアプリケーションは使用したことがないのですが、次の記述が該当するのかなと思います。

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/mac/source-editor?view=vsmac-2019

> Visual Studio for Mac では、コードの折りたたみは既定でオフになっています。
>   コードの折りたたみを有効にするには、**[Visual Studio] > [ユーザー設定] > [テキスト エディター] > [全般] > [コードの折りたたみ]** の順に移動します。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
その設定は有効になっているため、マウス操作ではソースを折りたたむことができるのですが、

なぜかスクリーンショットのように、キーボードのショートカットについては無効になってしまっているのです・・